# radio button enable/disable not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I am trying to switch my `radio` buttons either `true` or `false` using the following functionality.

But as a first click, I am not getting any response. Later on it works fine. ow to solve this issue and what is wrong here?

```js
var switching = false;

$('button').on("click", function() {
  switching = switching == false ? switching = true : switching = false;
  console.log("switching", switching); //first click true but not works!
  $(":radio").attr("disabled", switching);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Y" checked disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="X" disabled>

<button>
  Switch Me
</button>
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qqVGu/590/)

Comment: Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qqVGu/592/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just start from `true` and switch like this `switching = !switching`

```js
var switching = true;

$('button').on("click", function() {
  switching = !switching
  $(":radio").attr("disabled", switching);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Y" checked disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="X" disabled>

<button>
  Switch Me
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it just with one line:

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {
    $(":radio").prop('disabled', function(){ return !this.disabled });
});
```

```css
button.border { border:2px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Y" checked disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="X" disabled>

<button>Switch Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your ternary operator is incorrect** it should be :

```
switching = switching == false ? true : false;
```

so your code becomes :

var switching = false;

```
$('button').on("click", function(){
  switching = switching == false ? true : false;
  console.log( "switching", switching );
  $(":radio").attr("disabled", switching);

})
```

but the first click will not work with this so you need to initialize it as true.

```js
var switching = true;

$('button').on("click", function(){
  switching = switching == false ? true : false;
  console.log( "switching", switching );
  $(":radio").attr("disabled", switching);

})
```

```css
button.border{
border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Y" checked disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="X" disabled>

<button>
  Switch Me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check first whether is disable or not

```js
$('button').on("click", function() {

  if ($(":radio").prop('disabled')){
   $(":radio").attr("disabled", false);
  }
  else
  {
    $(":radio").attr("disabled", true);
  
  }
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Y" checked disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" disabled>
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="X" disabled>

<button>
  Switch Me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a common class in your HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Y" checked disabled class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="N" disabled class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="X" disabled class="radio">

<button>
  Switch Me
</button>
```

Now Here is your JS using class

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('button').on("click", function(){
    if($('.radio').is(':enabled')) {  
        $(".radio").attr("disabled", true);
    }else {  
        $(".radio").attr("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```